# Adding extra vertical line to the existing Dymola plot

Tags: plot, modelica, dymola, openmodelica

I have a graph which looks like this:

[image: Dymola Plot]

Please note that x-axis is NOT time but an arbitrary independent variable.

I need to draw vertical lines shown in the image above and label them. How can this be done in Dymola using the mos script?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I couldn't find anything else than manually adding a line via `plotArray()` the accompanying text by `plotText()`. See the Dymola-specific .mos-script below which should generate the plot at end.

```
// Simulate the model
simulateModel("Modelica.Mechanics.Rotational.Examples.CoupledClutches", stopTime=1.5, numberOfIntervals=0, outputInterval=0.001, resultFile="CoupledClutches");

// Create the actual plot
createPlot(id=1, position={191, 39, 672, 423}, x="clutch1.tau", y={"clutch1.phi_rel", "clutch1.w_rel"}, range={-10.0, 4.0, -200.0, 20.0}, grid=true, colors={{28,108,200}, {238,46,47}}, displayUnits={"deg", ""});

// Add the vertical line
plotArray(x={-8,-8},y={-200,0},color={0,128,0},thickness=0.5, erase=false);
plotArray(x={-2,-2},y={-200,0},color={128,0,128},thickness=0.5, erase=false);

// Add text
plotText(id=1, extent={{-9,-210}, {-7,-220}}, textString="Description 01", lineColor={0,128,0});
plotText(id=1, extent={{-3,-210}, {-1,-220}}, textString="Description 02", lineColor={128,0,128});
```

[image: Plot created by the code above]

If you want to use the legend for the description as you did in your mock-up, use the 'legend'-string parameter of the `plotArray()`-function instead of manually adding the text.

The script could for sure be enhanced by some more sophisticated dimensions for the arrays and texts, but this should be a good starting point. Also using `plotArrays()` combine the lines for the vertical lines.